# java readInt() on server doesn't get the good int

Tags: java, arrays, server, communication

I'm implementing a "little" client/server app, like a Cloud. 
The problem is: I'm new to Java.
So I've learned it a bit fast, and same for client/server communication, database, frames, threads.

I'm pretty sure my code won't be the best one, but the fact is: I have to use Java, and I have to do this fast. I won't try to optimize it, I just need it to work.

I have already implemented a lot, so I won't give all the code here, just explain what happens before my problem:
The main prog on client side opens a login frame. The client can register or login. Registration is working well, so let's say he logs in. If authentication works, that opens another frame, with "browse" and "upload" options. The idea is, he browse a file and then upload it. When he clicks on upload, it should call the upload function, which will send a byte[2] array to the server with a DataOutputStream object. (it sends first the size of the array, and then the array)

On the server side, when authentication works, it'll give the client socket to a "Cloud" class, which - until now - is just supposed to receive a byte array (it'll do more later, but for now I can't get this byte array)

But the server receives a size of 1970302063 instead of 2. I've checked the size before the `writeInt` on client size, it's 2. After the `readInt` on the server side, it's 1970302063.

I don't understand it. Can the server receive something else somewhere and my beautiful 2 be lost in a buffer?

Server side:

```java
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] zero) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket  ;
        Socket clientSocket ;
        int tmp = 0; //when everything works, tmp will disappear

        DataBase DB = new DataBase();
        System.out.println("ouverture du server");
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2017);


        while(tmp<1) { //limit the number of connections allowed.
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
                Thread t = new Thread(new Connect(clientSocket, DB));
                t.start();

                //clients.printAll(); //just to see the DB.

            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tmp++;      
        }    
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm authorising just 1 connection, because I'm still testing it and I don't want to change the port number each time I got an error / change something. With that I'll just have to restart server after each test.

```java
public class Connect implements Runnable{
    private DataBase DB;
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public Connect(Socket socket, DataBase DB) {
        this.clientSocket = socket;
        this.DB = DB;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in;
            PrintWriter out;
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            String mode = in.readLine();
            String clientID = in.readLine();
            String clientPwd = in.readLine();
            if (mode.equals("auth")) {
                Authentification auth = new Authentification (clientID, clientPwd, DB);
                out.write(auth.getMessage()+"\r\n");
                out.flush();
                if (auth.getMessage().equals("Login Successfull. Welcome in SecureCloud!"))
                    new Cloud(clientSocket, DB);    //launch Cloud.
            }
            else if (mode.equals("reg")) {
                Registration reg= new Registration(clientID, clientPwd, DB);
                out.write(reg.getMessage()+"\r\n");
                out.flush();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            this.clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Now, here: authentication and registration will set up a connection, and the client socket is closed at the end. BUT, if the authentication is successful, then it create a new Cloud:

```java
public class Cloud {
    public Cloud(Socket clientSocket, DataBase DB) {
        try {
            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            int length = dIn.readInt();                    // read length of incoming message
            System.out.println("byte array size: "+length);
            byte[] shorthash;
            if(length!=2) {
                System.err.println("Incorrect size for shorthash!");
            }

            else {
                shorthash = new byte[length];
                dIn.readFully(shorthash, 0, shorthash.length); // read the message
                System.out.println(shorthash);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, for now it doesn't do much. I know I'll have to add a while(true) loop so that the client can upload more files, but for now I'll be happy if I can send just this byte array.

Now, client side. I'll skip the main, it just open the login frame. I'll also skip most of the login Frame, it's just a frame...here is what happens when client click on "login":

```java
public  void    actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{ 
    if  (e.getSource()==connectButton) {
        Connection con = new Connection();
        con.auth(username.getText(), password.getText());
        if(con.getServerAnswer().equals("Login Successfull. Welcome in SecureCloud!")) {
            this.setVisible(false);
            con.setConnection(true);
            con.setUsername(username.getText());
            new Load_Frame(con.getUsername(),con.getSocket());
        }
        else System.out.println("erreur: " + con.getServerAnswer());
    }
    else if (e.getSource()==registerButton) {
        this.setVisible(false);
        new Registration_Frame();
    }
}
```

So, it creates the connection and launch the authentification process (con.auth) with username and password. If it's successfull, it'll open the Load Frame with the username and socket used for this connection. 
I'll skip again most of Load Frame, here are the actions:

```java
public  void    actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{ 
    if  (e.getSource()== uploadButton) {
        this.filename = uploadField.getText();
        File file = new File(filename);
        //TODO: change the upload function:
        try {
            client.upload(file);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (e.getSource()== downloadButton) {
        this.filename = downloadField.getText();
        //TODO: change the download function
        //download(filename);
    }

    else if (e.getSource()== browseButton) {
        JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
        if(jc.showOpenDialog(this) != 1)
            uploadField.setText(jc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

And, last but not least, the "upload" function, called by `client.upload(file)`:

```java
public void upload(File originalFile) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException {

    //create the "FileData" object, which make the shorthash of the file.
    FileData myfile = new FileData(originalFile, fileID);

    //say to the server that we want to upload:
    PrintWriter mode;
    mode = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    mode.println("upload");
    mode.flush();

    //Send shorthash to the server:
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("byte array size: "+myfile.shortHash.length);
    out.writeInt(myfile.shortHash.length); // send the length of the byte array
    //out.flush();
    out.write(myfile.shortHash);  //send the array

}
```

I've tried with and without the `out.flush()`, it doesn't make any difference.

With all that, here are the answers I get: 

From client:

```
Asking for authentification...
Login Successfull. Welcome in SecureCloud!
No file uploaded
byte array size: 2
```

From server:

```
Connection to SQLite has been established.
ouverture du server
byte array size: 1970302063
Incorrect size for shorthash!
```

Of course, since I know the size of the byte array, I could easily tell the server "hey, the size is 2!" (I mean, directly initialize my array with new byte[2] )
But I would like to understand what happens here. Plus, if I'm not receiving the good size, maybe I won't receive the good array.

Comment: You appear to be writing text and reading in binary. I suggest you do one or the other not both unless you like confusion.

Comment: 1970302063 is 0x75706C6F which is "uplo"

Comment: oh god, that's the point!
At first, the "upload" case was in my "connect" class, so i had a mode string just like for auth and reg. But then i put it in another class, and i didn't saw that my "upload" function was still sending the mode String -_-
It was really just that. Everything is working as it should and the server receive what i send, but i send a String for no reason -_- So stupid. 

Thank you for your help (and rapidity!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to the people who find the problem really fast :)
It was a bit of stupid, the kind of problem you don't see even if you reread your code 5 times, but then someone else read it he see that in a minute.

The solution is to delete this part in the upload function:

```
//say to the server that we want to upload:
PrintWriter mode;
mode = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
mode.println("upload");
mode.flush();
```

it was usefull until i changed the code on server side, and now it's just annoying ^^